# Export media library with metadata and import into new blog

Tags: post-meta, media, media-library

I am looking for a way to export my media directory, along with all meta data and import into a new blog

I can download all files via ftp, but i would lose all title and alt attributes associated with the files if I did that (thousands of images)

I am looking for a way to export the files, the meta data and import (either into the same folder structure or a new one)

Anyone have any ideas?  I have searched several sites, forums, blogs and stackexchange as best I could

Comment: Have you tried *Tools > Export > Media*?

Comment: I looked at that but it exports with an empty <description> and that is one of the fields I needed